# JAVA -JNA C function modify array of doubles

Tags: java, arrays, jna

I'm having trouble passing an array of doubles from Java to a C function with JNA that modifies the values by reference to the array.

C example function:

```
void examplefunct(double* dd) //<-- this wants an array of 6 doubles
```

this function requires an array of 6 doubles, now I've tried using

```
DoubleByReference[] jdd = new DoubleByReference[6];
```

in the JNA implementation but I'm failing at getting values from the array.
Honestly I think my implementation is incorrect, a basic example would be much appreciated since I'm new to JNA

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem is that the C function is expecting an array of doubles (not by reference) but on the Java side you've got an array of Java object instances rather than an array of doubles. Anyway, here's an example of sending an array of doubles to C: http://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/example08.html

Comment: have you tried just sending a double array? i.e. `double[] jdd = new double[6]`

Comment: Hot Damn @neuronaut you sir do rock. The link worked just needed to set the pointer up properly. Non of the DoubleByRef business.

Comment: Yea @BevynQ that doesn't work, but if you got a working example that might be way easier.

Comment: `DoubleByReference` passes the address of a single `double` (similar to passing an array of length one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can map this function:

```
public interface MyLibrary extends Library {
    void examplefunct(Pointer dd);
    void examplefunct(java.nio.Buffer dd);
    void examplefunct(double[] dd);
}
```

If you allocate an instance of `com.sun.jna.Memory`, you can use the various memory accessor functions to write doubles into the buffer.

If you use a direct NIO ByteBuffer, you can use the second example.

If you use a Java primitive array, then JNA performs the copy from Java to native memory for you.

Each of these has different performance characteristics, so you should test within your environment if performance is of concern.

Comment: I ended up using Pointer and thats working fine, i didn't think of using double[] that would actually make things a bit easier/cleaner code-wise